# Number of d-Calabi-Yau partitions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, partitions

This problem arises from algebraic geometry/representation theory, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0668.pdf (chapter 2).

We call a partition $p=[p_1,...,p_n]$ with $2 \leq p_1 \leq p_2 \leq ... \leq p_n$ **d-Calabi-Yau** (for $d \geq 1$)  when $n-d-1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{p_i}}$.

For example for $d=1$ there are 4 1-Calabi-Yau partitions: [2,2,2,2],[3,3,3],[2,4,4] and [2,3,6]. For $d=2$ there are 18, see example 2.15. (b) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0668.pdf .

> Question 1: Is there a nice formula for the $d$-Calabi-Yau partitions for a fixed $d$?

It seems hard to calculate the number for $d \geq 3$ even with a computer since a term $p_i$ can be pretty big.

> Question 2: For a given $d$, what is the maximal value a term $p_i$ can have?

For $d=1$ it is 6 and for $d=2$ it is 42.

Comment: A remark, there exist reasonable good upper bound estimate for the number of the solution of $M=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_{i}}$ when fixing $M$, I believe it occurs in a paper of Jean Bourgain, maybe also help for this case.

Comment: @katago Looking through MathSciNet, the most recent upper bound may be Browning & Elsholtz 2011, something like $(1.264085)^{(5/12)^{2^{n-1}}}$.  So the short answer to Q1 is no!

Answer (score 14):

When $d=n-2$ (which constitutes the bulk of the cases) these partitions are known as Egyptian fractions, and their number is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A002966. No closed formula seems to exist.

For arbitrary $n$ and $d$ there is http://oeis.org/A156869, but one has to be careful because the value 1 is allowed there. So whilst there is no nice formula, the number of $d$-CY partitions should be given by http://oeis.org/A156871 (with the caveat that 1 is allowed).

For your second question, one has to list all Egyptian fractions (but that is not a straightforward thing to do) and read off the answer, although there might be an algorithm to write down the "biggest" partition somehow. In any case, the maximum for $d=3$ seems to be 1806 if I'm not mistaken (see also https://oeis.org/A007018).

Comment: Nice find on A007018!

Answer (score 6):

Following up on @pbelmans's answer and researching an article mentioned in [OEIS A007018](https://oeis.org/A007018), I believe your Question 2 was answered just under 100 years ago by David Curtiss (On Kellogg's Diophantine problem, *Amer. Math. Monthly* 29 (1922) 380-387).*

Curtiss confirms Kellogg's conjecture that the maximum $x_i$ in any $$\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x_n} = 1$$ is given by the sequence $u_1 = 1$ and $u_{k+1} = u_k(u_k+1)$ which begins 1, 2, 6, 42, 1806, 3263442.  On p386 he explains, "But the value $u_n$ is actually attained by giving to the $x$'s the values $u_k+1$, so that $u_n$ is the maximum of $f_{n-1}(x)$." (That last expression is something he defined to simplify the proof.)  Indeed,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{1+1} + \frac{1}{2+1} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = 1, \\
\frac{1}{1+1} + \frac{1}{2+1} + \frac{1}{6+1} + \frac{1}{42} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{42} = 1, \\
\frac{1}{1+1} + \frac{1}{2+1} + \frac{1}{6+1} + \frac{1}{42+1} + \frac{1}{1806} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{43} + \frac{1}{1806} = 1, \dots
\end{gather*}

* There's also a [sci.math.research](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/numth/egypt/curtiss.html) thread from 1996 where a claim that Curtiss's proof is wrong is retracted, but the proof does seem to be difficult to follow. Gerry Myerson provided a reference to a simpler 1995 proof by Izhboldin and Kurliandchik.

---

I'm including a comment to @katago here so that answers to both questions are in one place.
Looking through MathSciNet, the most recent upper bound may be Browning & Elsholtz 2011, something like $$(1.264085...)^{(5/12)^{2^{n−1}}}$$ where apparently the 1.26 is a known constant that arises in these problems.  There are also lower bounds in the literature.

So the short answer to Q1 is no, at least not yet.